# Hql "in" statement doesn't work with an @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

I have a class collection property with `@ElementCollection` and `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`
I am trying to perform an in statement on that collection however in the generated sql i get this -> `{non-qualified-property-ref} in (?)`

I might be doing something wrong while creating the hql itself. Could it be because the elements are actually enum values ?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the 'in elements' expression, according to the documentation ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html):

```
select mother from Cat as mother, Cat as kit
where kit in elements(foo.kittens)
```

However, there is an open bug in Hibernate... it doesn't work as you might expect for enum values, see: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5159 for a workaround.